# Arduino code- to do the same operation every minute

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to run the following code. But I couldn't get the expected result. It is for an Arduino-based system. I need to run some Tests. Each test has two parameters. The number of 'Samples' and how long each sample to be tested. For example, if the s_count = 5 and t_count = 10, there are a total of 5 samples and each sample should be tested for 10 minutes. During this 10 minutes sample, I want to generate the result every minute and at the end, I calculate the average (of 10 minutes result). Following is my code. I ended up in an infinite loop inside the second while loop. Any suggestions, please.

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 60000;

void startTest(int s_count, int t_count)
{

  int sample_number = s_count;
  int test_time = t_count;

        while(sample_number > 0)
        {
                while(test_time >0)
                {
                        unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

                        // do measurement every one minute
                        if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
                        {
                                previousMillis = currentMillis;

                                doTest();
                                test_time--;
                        }
                }

                // reset the time counter after finishing one sample
                test_time = t_count;

               // go to the next sample

                sample_number--;
        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger, and inspect the value of `t_count` and `test_time`. Have you tried that?

Comment: *But I couldn't get the expected result*. What specifically does this mean? What were you expecting? What did you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
bool done=false;
 if(done==false&&millis()%60000<100){
  functions here
  done=true;
  }
```